# Using streams how to replace a value of the nested list

Tags: java, java-stream

First half of the strings encountered in the inputs in the index position 1 are to be replaced with  the character "-"  using streams how can we perform the operations?

```
List<List<String>> arr = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("0", "ab"), Arrays.asList("6", "cd"),
    Arrays.asList("0", "ef"), Arrays.asList("6", "gh"),
    Arrays.asList("4", "ij"), Arrays.asList("0", "ab"),
    Arrays.asList("6", "cd"));
```

I have the above list I wanted replace the 1st position of each nested list value with "-" using loops I have done like this

```
    int j=0;
    while(j <arr.size()/2){
        arr.get(j).set(1, "-");
        j++;

        }
```

Sample output:[[0, -], [6, -], [0, -], [6, gh], [4, ij], [0, ab], [6, cd]]

But any one can explain how the same can be achieved using streams

Comment: What do you mean by “first half of the strings”? Could you also give the same output you expect for this example? What have you tried so far to do it?

Comment: I have the above list I wanted replace the 1st position of each nested list value with "-" using loops I have done like this
  int j=0;
    while(j <arr.size()/2){
        arr.get(j).set(1, "-");
        j++;

        }
  Sample output:[[0, -], [6, -], [0, -], [6, gh], [4, ij], [0, ab], [6, cd]]

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague. Better to give the output format too so that someone can understand what you need and help you. However based on some assumptions and heuristics, I guess this what you need. If you want a different formatting, please let me know or change this answer accordingly.

Another point here is what you have tried so far is not clear. You have to give it a try upfront and mention what you have done when the question is posted.

```
List<List<String>> formattedStrings = source.stream()
    .map(sl -> IntStream.range(0, sl.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> i == 1 ? sl.get(i).charAt(0) + "-" + sl.get(i).charAt(1) : sl.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I have the above list I wanted replace the 1st position of each nested list value with "-" using loops I have done like this
  int j=0;
    while(j <arr.size()/2){
        arr.get(j).set(1, "-");
        j++;

        }
  Sample output:[[0, -], [6, -], [0, -], [6, gh], [4, ij], [0, ab], [6, cd]]
  
  How can I acheie the same function using stream

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `Stream` to do this, working on a sublist would be simpler:

```
arr.subList(0, arr.size() / 2).forEach(s -> s.set(1, "-"));
```

If you really need to work with streams (e.g. if you want to do additional filtering and mapping operations), you could do it with either an `IntStream` to work on the indexes:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.size() / 2)
        .forEach(j -> arr.get(j).set(1, "-"));
```

or simply by limiting the number of entries you process:

```
arr.stream()
        .limit(arr.size() / 2)
        .forEach(s -> s.set(1, "-"));
```